# Xamarin.ios CollectionView Delete and Insert Items

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin.ios, uicollectionview

I am currently developing an iphone app with xamarin in visual studio. I'm a beginner..

I use a CollectionView. This has a list and includes 8 items with different ID's in the CollectionViewSource.cs:

```
ProductCategoryList.Add (new ProductCategorys () {Categoryid = 1, ProductCategoryName = "testname", ProductCategoryImage = UIImage.FromFile ( "productcat / maincat / testpic.jpg")});
```

Now I would like, if an item is pressed, delete All Items and refill it.
In the ProductCategoryCollectionDelegate.cs i have:

```
Public override Boolean ShouldSelectItem (UICollectionView collectionView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
```

For the delete and insert I have found these 2 methods

```
Public void DeleteItems (NSIndexPath [] indexPaths)
Public void InsertItems (NSIndexPath [] indexPaths)
```

(The xamarin Documentation is very scarce)

How can I use this 2 metodes to completely empty the list and add new items?

thanks for help

Comment: HI Andreas, Did you resolve the issue? I am stuck at the same issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've taken a `TableView` instead of the `CollectionView`.
With this function it is possible to directly delete items in the `Tablesource` class:

```
public override void CommitEditingStyle(UITableView tableView,
                          UITableViewCellEditingStyle editingStyle,
                          Foundation.NSIndexPath indexPath)
{
        switch (editingStyle)
        {
            case UITableViewCellEditingStyle.Delete:
                AppDelegate.DAUtil.setBasketItemStatusByBasketID(
                   basketitems[indexPath.Row].ZBASKETID, "2");
                // remove the item from the underlying data source
                basketitems.RemoveAt(indexPath.Row);
                // delete the row from the table
                tableView.DeleteRows(new NSIndexPath[] { indexPath },
                   UITableViewRowAnimation.Fade);
                break;
            case UITableViewCellEditingStyle.None:
                Console.WriteLine("CommitEditingStyle:None called");
                break;
        }
}

public override bool CanEditRow(UITableView tableView,
                            NSIndexPath indexPath)
{
        return true;
     // return false if you wish to disable editing
     // for a specific indexPath or for all rows
}
```

The Source of the Table is a List. Alternatively, you can reload the `TableSource` with:

```
tablename.ReloadData();
```